# How to use POJO with Quarkus and MongoDB in Kotlin

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, find, pojo, quarkus

I am using Quarkus and Kotlin, and I need to save and retrieve documents in a MongoDB collection.

I have defined a *data class*:

```
data class Result constructor(
    @BsonId
    val id: String? = null,
    val values: Map<String, Any> = mapOf()
)
```

The *StorageService* has an attribute like this:

```
private var collection: MongoCollection<Result>
```

To insert a result, I define an instance of the class and I use the *insertOne* method:

```
val result = Result(id="exampleId", values=mapOf("one" to 1, "two" to 2))
...
collection.insertOne(result)
```

**This works** and I see the document stored in the collection with the correct id.

When I do the *find* **it doesn't work**:

```
val result = collection.find(eq("_id", "exampleId")).first()
```

The `println(result)` gives:

> Result(id=null, values={})

Can you tell me where am I doing wrong, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide you own codec for your classes, the POJO codec will be used.

There is some small stuff to be done for it to works with data classes, this is documented inside the MongoDB with Panache guide, even if you don't use MongoDB with Panache it will still apply: https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb-panache#working-with-kotlin-data-classes

There is a Kotlin version of MongoDB with Panache, but it's not yet documented.